# How do I differentiate WSS and Moss for conditional compilation?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I do not want to create multiple projects to compile WSS and Moss separately.  How do I create conditionals to compile different Sharepoint versions?  How can the versions be differentiated?

Sample to express intent:

```
#if Moss
//reference a dll specific for moss
#elif WSS
//reference a dll specific for wss
#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [define constants in csproj](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291516/define-constants-in-csproj)